# Fourier Transform Properties Established

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have a function, f, in $L_1(R)$. I need to establish the following fourier transforms and I don't know how to do so. Can anyone guide me through one of these that would then help me get the other ones?

1. If $ g(x) = f(x + h)$ then $\hat g(\xi) =  \hat f(\xi)e^{2\pi ih\xi}$ for any $h \in R$
2. If $g(x) = f(\delta x)$ then $\hat g(\xi) = \delta^{−1} \hat f (\delta^{−1}  \xi)$ for any $\delta > 0$.

Comment: Try writing down the definition of $\hat f(x)$, $\hat f(x+h)$ and $\hat f(\delta x)$ for a start? PS: the Latex for "hat" is ... \hat{.}

Comment: @AlexHalm can you point me in a direction where I can find these definitions? Unfortunately, I do not have a fourier textbook.

Comment: Wikipedia ? Google ?

Comment: @AlexHalm I got both of these figured out. Now my question is (for my own personal curiosity), how would these change if the function was in $L_1(R^2)$ rather than $L_1(R)$?